# How do I get rid of all roles of the user discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I was making my mute command and I thought of getting rid of all the member's role but I don't know how to get rid of all the member's roles I even tried

```
for role in member.roles:
                
   await member.remove_roles(role)
```

But it gave me this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

Any suggestion or ideas!

My code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None, reason="No reason provided", *, time: time_str.convert = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)):
        guild = ctx.guild
        muted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
        time_converted = time.total_seconds()
        if member is None:
            await ctx.send("You need to mention someone in order to mute them")
            return
        if member == ctx.author:
            await ctx.send("You can't mute yourself")
            return
        if muted_role in member.roles:
            await ctx.send("They are already muted")
            return
        if muted_role is None:
            await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
        else:
            if time_converted == 0:  
                mutedembed = discord.Embed(title="**Muted!**")
                mutedembed.add_field(name=f'ID:', value=f'{member.id}', inline=False)
                mutedembed.add_field(name=f"Name:", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
                mutedembed.add_field(name=f'Reason:', value=f"{reason}")
                mutedembed.add_field(name="Time", value=time)
                mutedembed.add_field(name=f'By:', value=f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}', inline=False)
                mutedembed.set_thumbnail(url="")
                await ctx.send(embed=mutedembed)
                for role in member.roles:
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                await member.add_roles(muted_role)

            if time_converted == 1 or time_converted > 1:
                tempmutedembed = discord.Embed(title="**Temp Muted!**")
                tempmutedembed.set_author(icon_url=member.avatar_url, name=f'{member} has been temp muted!')
                tempmutedembed.add_field(name=f'ID:', value=f'{member.id}', inline=False)
                tempmutedembed.add_field(name=f"Name:", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
                tempmutedembed.add_field(name=f'Reason:', value=f"{reason}")
                tempmutedembed.add_field(name=f"Time", value=time)
                tempmutedembed.add_field(name=f'By:', value=f'{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}', inline=False)
                tempmutedembed.set_thumbnail(url=f"https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/818899477372600434/835563020402556938/1200px-Bw-muted.png?width=586&height=586")
                tempmutedembed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                

                await ctx.send(embed=tempmutedembed)
                for role in member.roles:
                    await member.remove_roles(role)
                await member.add_roles(muted_role)
                await asyncio.sleep(time_converted)
                unmutedembed = discord.Embed(title="**UnMuted!**")
                unmutedembed.set_author(icon_url=member.avatar_url, name=f'{member} has been temp muted!')
                unmutedembed.add_field(name=f'ID:', value=f'{member.id}', inline=False)
                unmutedembed.add_field(name=f"Name:", value=f"{member.name}#{member.discriminator}")
                unmutedembed.set_thumbnail(url=f"")
                unmutedembed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                await ctx.send(embed=unmutedembed)                
                await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
```

Thanks for all of your support. It helps alot!

Comment: ignore the thumbnail and the image. They have been deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all roles just `edit` the `member` as the following:

```py
await member.edit(roles=[]) # Removes every role
```

To request the role and do not get an error we use `ctx.guild.roles`, not `guild.roles`.

**Your request would be:**

```py
muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
```

Comment: sorry but same error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): 
Unknown Role It doesnt leave traceback

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with how you request the other role? In which line is the error occuring?

Comment: it didnt leave a traceback

Comment: Well, you provided one? Maybe you are requesting the guild in the wrong way.

Comment: muted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")

Comment: thats how i did my muted role

Comment: `ctx.guild.roles` should be the correct way to get the role.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `member.roles` list includes the `@everyone` role which is inherent to all the members and cannot be removed. It is the first element in the list. Try editing the loop line to be:

```py
for role in member.roles[1:]:
```

Comment: sorry but it is same error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role It doesnt leave traceback

Comment: Is the error actually in this line? It could be in `discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")` and you may not have the role called "Muted" in the guild.

Comment: I guess it should be `ctx.guild.roles`, not only `guild.roles`

Comment: It is same error again
What i did was:
`await member.remove_roles(role)`

Comment: Well thanks for your help. But the @Dominik solved it