# discord.py remove every role from list of rols

Tags: python, discord.py

I am in the process of building a bot that can remove many roles. So far I can get a list of all the roles that I want to remove from the member. But I don't want to remove all of the roles at once as the length of the list can be anything between 2 and 50. I know that I can remove multiple roles with

```
member.remove_roles (Role1, Role2, Role3 ...)
```

but I don't know how many roles there are in the list so I don't really know how to elegantly remove all of the roles. Maybe one of you can help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get rid of all roles of the user discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67493931/how-do-i-get-rid-of-all-roles-of-the-user-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use member.edit and pass in a list of roles that the member should have. Sice you want to remove the roles you can just get the current roles and subtract the ones you wanna remove

```py
# list_of_roles = [role1, role2]
await member.edit(roles=set(member.roles)-set(list_of_roles))
```

We cast the list to a set since you can't subtract lists, but you can subtract sets

I just checked the code for member.remove_roles and [it also uses member.edit](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/member.py#L885), so this is just a faster way to remove roles

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop, like this:

```
for role in role_list:
    if role in member.roles:
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: Yeah I know but the Problem with that is, that I get rate limited then

Comment: Use cool downs then. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087253/cooldown-for-command-on-discord-bot-python) is a stackoverflow question

Comment: Hmm okay, the rate limit for editing roles seems to be 1000 every 24 hours. You could hit that with this solution if you trigger loads at once, but i see you already got a better solution for your problem, glad you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

With the help from [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14449816/dominik) I Came up with a Solution that looks Like this

```
            for member in guild.members:
                print(member)
                roles2 = member.roles
                c = 0
                for r in roles2:
                    print(r)
                    if r.id in roles:
                        roles2.pop(c)
                    c += 1
                print(roles2)
                await member.edit(roles = roles2)
```

This Code Removes every Role from a role which Id is in another List called roles